# Solving Differential equations with 7 unknowns

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I want to solve the 7 differential equations which are functions of time for the 7 unknowns.
I wanted to find the solutions of the equations:

```
eo(t)=f1(e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
e1(t)=f2(e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
e2(t)=f3(e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
e3(t)=f4(e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
w1(t)=f5(e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
w2(t)=f6(e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
w3(t)=f7(e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
```

I have generated the equations of `e0, e1, e2, e3, w1, w2, w3`.
Now, how do I solve these equations, and which commands are needed?

I need to find the values of `e0, e1, e2, e3, w1, w2, w3` and get the numerical value of these with respect to `t`.

The equations which have to be solved are

```
e0 = - (e_1(t)*w_1(t))/2 - (e_2(t)*w_2(t))/2 - (e_3(t)*w_3(t))/2
e1 = (e_0(t)*w_1(t))/2 - (e_2(t)*w_3(t))/2 - (e_3(t)*w_2(t))/2
e2 =(e_0(t)*w_2(t))/2 - (e_1(t)*w_3(t))/2 + (e_3(t)*w_1(t))/2
e3 = (e_0(t)*w_3(t))/2 + (e_1(t)*w_2(t))/2 - (e_2(t)*w_1(t))/2
w1 = w_2(t)*(1.98019*e_3(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) + 1.980*e_0(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t)) - 1.980*e_1(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t)) - 1.9801*e_2(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t))) - 1.0*w_1(t)*(1.0*e_0(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) + 1.0*e_1(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t)) - 1.0*e_2(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t)) - 1.0*e_3(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t))) - 1.0*w_3(t)*(1.0*e_0(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t)) - 1.0*e_2(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) + 1.0*e_1(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t)) + 1.0*e_3(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t))) - (63.366*kappa^2*(0.72470*w_1(t) + 0.355*kappa*(2.0*e_0(t)e_1(t)(2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) + 2.0*e_1(t)*e_2(t)) + 2.0*e_1(t)e_3(t)(e_0(t)^2 - 1.0*e_1(t)^2 + e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2)) - 0.3623*kappa*((e_0(t)^2 + e_1(t)^2 - 1.0*e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2)*(e_0(t)^2 - 1.0*e_1(t)^2 + e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2) + (2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) + 2.0*e_1(t)e_2(t))(2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) - 2.0*e_1(t)*e_2(t)))))/(l^5*rho)
w2 = w_3(t)*(0.505*e_1(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) - 0.505*e_0(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t)) + 0.505*e_2(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t)) + 0.505*e_3(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t))) - 1.0*w_1(t)*(0.505*e_3(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) + 0.505*e_0(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t)) - 0.505*e_1(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t)) - 0.505*e_2(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t))) - 1.0*w_2(t)*(1.0*e_0(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) + 1.0*e_1(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t)) - 1.0*e_2(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t)) - 1.0*e_3(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t))) - (32.0*kappa^2*(0.7184*w_2(t) - 0.3592*kappa*(2.0*e_0(t)e_1(t)(e_0(t)^2 + e_1(t)^2 - 1.0*e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2) + 2.0*e_1(t)e_3(t)(2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) - 2.0*e_1(t)*e_2(t)))))/(l^5*rho)
w3 = w_1(t)*(1.0*e_2(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) - 1.0*e_0(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t)) + 1.0*e_1(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t)) + 1.0*e_3(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)w_2(t))) + w_2(t)(1.980*e_0(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t)) - 1.980*e_1(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) + 1.980*e_2(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t)) + 1.980*e_3(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t))) - 1.0*w_3(t)*(1.0*e_0(t)*(e_1(t)*w_1(t) + e_2(t)*w_2(t) + e_3(t)*w_3(t)) + 1.0*e_1(t)*(e_2(t)*w_3(t) - 1.0*e_0(t)*w_1(t) + e_3(t)*w_2(t)) - 1.0*e_2(t)*(e_0(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_1(t)*w_3(t) + e_3(t)*w_1(t)) - 1.0*e_3(t)*(e_0(t)*w_3(t) + e_1(t)*w_2(t) - 1.0*e_2(t)*w_1(t))) + (63.366*kappa^2*(0.3551*kappa*((e_0(t)^2 + e_1(t)^2 - 1.0*e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2)*(e_0(t)^2 - 1.0*e_1(t)^2 + e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2) - 1.0*(2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) + 2.0*e_1(t)e_2(t))(2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) - 2.0*e_1(t)*e_2(t))) - 0.724*w_3(t) + 0.362*kappa*((e_0(t)^2 + e_1(t)^2 - 1.0*e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2)*(e_0(t)^2 - 1.0*e_1(t)^2 + e_2(t)^2 - 1.0*e_3(t)^2) + (2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) + 2.0*e_1(t)e_2(t))(2.0*e_0(t)*e_3(t) - 2.0*e_1(t)*e_2(t)))))/(l^5*rho)
```

I used this code in MATLAB after assigning the values

```
soll=ode45(e0,e1,e2,e3,w1,w2,w3,e_0(t),e_1(t),e_2(t),e_3(t),w_1(t),w_2(t),w_3(t))
```

But I got the following error message:

> Undefined function 'exist' for input arguments of type 'sym'.
>
> Error in odearguments (line 59) if (exist(ode)==2)
>
> Error in ode45 (line 113) [neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0, odeArgs, odeFcn, ...

Please enlighten me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: are these differential equations first order or multiple order?

Comment: @cbahadir
this is a first order equations

Comment: you can also try `fsolve()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that `ode45` cannot solve symbolic equations (your variables are of type 'sym'). In fact [ode45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method) is a numerical solver which works on functions, not on symbolical expressions. Here's how to [define a function in Matlab](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25568-defining-functions):

> First, you need to create a new m-file then type this code

```
function y = f(x)
y = 2 * (x^3) + 7 * (x^2) + x;
```

> Save with filename 'f.m'